# vswitch not found hyperV while running minikube start

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I had created a Virtual switch with the name "Minikube2" . Previously I had created  Virtual switch with the name "minikube" ,but deleted it later as there was config issue.

Did all the required configuration -"sharing on ethernet .."

Now when I try to run

minikube start --kubernetes-version="v1.10.3" --vm-driver="hyperv" --hyperv-virtual-switch="minikube2"

it downloads the ISO , but fails to configure the switch -

it says vswitch "minikube2" not found

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer is to delete `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\.minikube` and try again.
Below is my investigation:

First I have created Virtual Switch "minikube", started the cluster and it worked as expected. 
Then I stopped minikube, created new "Minikube2" switch and started minikube

```
minikube start --kubernetes-version="v1.10.3" --vm-driver="hyperv" --hyperv-virtual-switch="minikube2" --v=9
```

Appeared issue:

> Starting local Kubernetes v1.10.3 cluster... Starting VM... [executing
>   ==>] : C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -NonInteractive ( Hyper-V\Get-VM minikube ).state [stdout =====>] : Off
>
> [stderr =====>] : [executing ==>] :
>   C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile
>   -NonInteractive Hyper-V\Start-VM minikube [stdout =====>] : [stderr =====>] : Hyper-V\Start-VM : 'minikube' failed to start. Synthetic Ethernet Port (Instance ID AF9D08DC-2625-4F24-93E5-E09BAD904899):
>   Error 'Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested
>   service.'. Failed to allocate resources while connecting to a virtual
>   network. The Ethernet switch may not exist. 'minikube' failed to
>   start. (Virtual machine ID 863D6558-78EC-4648-B712-C1FDFC907588)
>   'minikube' Synthetic Ethernet Port: Failed to finish reserving
>   resources with Error 'Insufficient system resources exist to complete
>   the requested service.' (0x800705AA). (Virtual machine ID
>   863D6558-78EC-4648-B712-C1FDFC907588) 'minikube' failed to allocate
>   resources while connecting to a virtual network: Insufficient system
>   resources exist to complete the requested service. (0x800705AA)
>   (Virtual Machine ID 863D6558-78EC-4648-B712-C1FDFC907588). The
>   Ethernet switch may not exist. Could not find Ethernet switch
>   'minikube'. At line:1 char:1
>   + Hyper-V\Start-VM minikube
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Start-VM], VirtualizationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Unspecified,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.StartVM
>
> E1022 12:50:43.384867    6216 start.go:168] Error starting host: Error
>   starting stopped host: exit status 1.
>
> Retrying. E1022 12:50:43.398832    6216 start.go:174] Error starting
>   host:  Error starting stopped host: exit status 1 PS
>   C:\Windows\system32>

Then I deleted `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\.minikube` , minikube vm inside Hyper-V and started again:

```
C:\Windows\system32> minikube start --kubernetes-version="v1.10.3" --vm-driver="hyperv" --hyperv-virtual-switch="minikube2" --v=9
```

Result:

> Starting local Kubernetes v1.10.3 cluster... Starting VM...
>
> Downloading Minikube ISO
>
> 170.78 MB / 170.78 MB [============================================] 100.00% 0s 
>   Creating CA: C:\Users\Vitalii.minikube\certs\ca.pem
>
> Creating client certificate: C:\Users\Vitalii.minikube\certs\cert.pem
>
> ----- [stderr =====>] : Using switch "Minikube2"
>
> ----- Moving files into cluster...
>
> Downloading kubeadm v1.10.3
>
> Downloading kubelet v1.10.3 Finished
>
> Downloading kubeadm v1.10.3 Finished
>
> Finished Downloading kubelet v1.10.3
>
> Setting up certs... Connecting to
>
> cluster... Setting up kubeconfig...
>
> Starting cluster components...
>
> Kubectl is now configured to use the cluster.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                    READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   coredns-c4cffd6dc-cjzsm                 1/1       Running   0          1m
kube-system   etcd-minikube                           1/1       Running   0          56s
kube-system   kube-addon-manager-minikube             1/1       Running   0          13s
kube-system   kube-apiserver-minikube                 1/1       Running   0          41s
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-minikube        1/1       Running   0          1m
kube-system   kube-dns-86f4d74b45-w62rv               2/3       Running   0          1m
kube-system   kube-proxy-psgss                        1/1       Running   0          1m
kube-system   kube-scheduler-minikube                 1/1       Running   0          21s
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard-6f4cfc5d87-jz266   1/1       Running   0          1m
kube-system   storage-provisioner                     1/1       Running   0          1m
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like HyperV driver has some problems running Minikube. For me when trying to run it on Windows it was much simpler to use the docker driver. Just run:

```
minikube start --driver=docker
```

and it works without problems. Make sure your docker daemon is running e.g. with Docker Desktop. For reference about drivers look here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/learning-environment/minikube/#specifying-the-vm-driver